# When I run mvn clean it's wrong

Tags: maven

When I use maven scope import import the dependency get the cycle

> [ERROR]   The project
>   com.example:websocket-dependencies:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
>   (D:\code_local\fmt\websocket\websocket-dependencies\pom.xml) has 1
>   error  [ERROR]     The dependencies of type=pom and with scope=import
>   form a cycle: com.example:websocket-dependencies:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT ->
>   com.example:websocket-dependencies:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

the pom.xml is that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>websocket</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>web</module>
        <module>websocket-dependencies</module>
        <module>entity</module>
    </modules>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>websocket</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.6.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <spring.boot.verison>1.5.9.RELEASE</spring.boot.verison>
    </properties>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.verison}</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.example</groupId>
                <artifactId>websocket-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <env>dev</env>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>test</id>
            <properties>
                <env>test</env>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <env>prod</env>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>websocket</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>websocket-dependencies</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>websocket-dependencies</name>
    <description>websocket-dependencies</description>
    <properties>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <profiles>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

When I run `mvn clean -x` it get the error detail:

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective settings
[WARNING] Unrecognised tag: 'mirror' (position: START_TAG seen ...he preferred\n   | server for that repository.\n   |-->\n    <mirror>... @146:13)  @ D:\soft\apache-maven-3.3.9\conf\settings.xml, line 146, column 13
[WARNING]
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin is missing. @ com.example:websocket:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, D:\code_local\fmt\websocket\pom.xml, line 52, column 21
[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Could not find artifact com.example:websocket-dependencies:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT @ com.example:websocket:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, D:\code_local\fmt\websocket\pom.xml, line 38, column 25
 @
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin is missing. @ com.example:websocket:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, D:\code_local\fmt\websocket\pom.xml, line 52, column 21
[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Could not find artifact com.example:websocket-dependencies:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT @ com.example:websocket:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, D:\code_local\fmt\websocket\pom.xml, line 38, column 25

    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:422)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.collectProjects(DefaultGraphBuilder.java:419)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.getProjectsForMavenReactor(DefaultGraphBuilder.java:410)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.build(DefaultGraphBuilder.java:83)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.buildGraph(DefaultMaven.java:491)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:219)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project com.example:web:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (D:\code_local\fmt\websocket\web\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Could not find artifact com.example:websocket-dependencies:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT @ com.example:websocket:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, D:\code_local\fmt\websocket\pom.xml, line 38, column 25 -> [Help 2]
org.apache.maven.model.resolution.UnresolvableModelException: Could not find artifact com.example:websocket-dependencies:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
        at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel(ProjectModelResolver.java:197)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.importDependencyManagement(DefaultModelBuilder.java:1192)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:455)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in D:\soft\apache-maven-3.3.9\conf\settings.xml, line 146, column 13.

In this way maven, most probably, is not able to resolve your **websocket-dependencies** dependency.

Maybe fixing the settings.xml will solve the cycle.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I found the answer. As suggested, there is a circular reference in my pom import, which causes this problem.